# Calculate with the total value

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database with the following structure:

```
trans
- id
- user_id
- k_id
- left
- right
```

I am trying to get the total value in the column `left` with `COALESCE(SUM(left),0) as total1`. Also selecting the total value in column `right` with `COALESCE(SUM(right),0) as total2`.

For that part the code is working.

After that I want to show the `SUM(total1 - total2) AS total`

When I run this statement I get an error:
`Unknown column 'total1' in field list`

Does someone know how I can fix this problem?

Here is my full statement:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(left),0) as total1, COALESCE(SUM(right),0) as total2, SUM(total1 - total2) AS total FROM trans WHERE user_id='2' AND k_id='120'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, you cannot re-use column aliases in the `SELECT` where they are defined.  The reason is simple:  SQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `SELECT`

So, repeat the expressions:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(left), 0) as total1,
       COALESCE(SUM(right), 0) as total2,
       (COALESCE(SUM(left), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(right), 0)) as total
FROM trans
WHERE user_id = 2 AND k_id = 120;
```

Note that I removed the single quotes from the constants in the `WHERE`.  Ids are usually numbers.  Numbers should be compared to numbers not strings.  If the ids really are strings then, of course, the single quotes are appropriate and correct.